# Links connected but not visible

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

The graph connects the nodes proper but the links are not visible. I added the `.attr("stroke", "black")` `.attr("stroke-width", 2)` directly in the `update()` function. Before I had it in CSS which also wasn´t working. The browser inspector is telling me that the x, y positons are 0 for my link group. Which irritates me, usually those positions are provided in the `ticked()` function, by source.x,y and target.x,y.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>D3v4 enter().exit().remove()</title>
    <!-- favcon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="https://networkrepository.com/favicon.png">
    <!-- call external d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <!-- import multiselection framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.js"></script>
    <!-- import "font awesome" stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .canvas {
        background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
    }

    .node_group {
        fill: whitesmoke;
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 2px
    }

    .node_label {
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 0px;
        fill: black
    }

    .tooltip {
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: left;
        background: rgb(245, 245, 245);
        border: 2px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border-style: solid;
        pointer-events: none;
        line-height: 150%;
        padding: 8px 10px;
    }

    #context-menu {
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 10000;
        width: 190px;
        background: whitesmoke;
        border: 2px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border-color: white;
        border-style: solid;
        transform: scale(0);
        transform-origin: top left;
    }

    #context-menu.active {
        transform: scale(1);
        transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out;
    }

    #context-menu .item {
        padding: 8px 10px;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: black;
    }

    #context-menu .item i {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    #context-menu hr {
        margin: 5px 0px;
        border-color: whitesmoke;
    }

    #context-menu .item:hover {
        background: lightblue;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <!-- right click context menu -->
    <div id="context-menu">
        <div id="addObject" class="item">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Node
        </div>
        <div id="removeObject" class="item">
            <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> Remove Node
        </div>
    </div>

    <svg id="svg"> </svg>


    <!-- call script where the main application is written -->
    <script>
        var graph = {
            "nodes": [{
                "id": 0,
                "name": "Company",
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "1",
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "2",
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "3",
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "4",
            }
            ],
            "links": [{
                "source": 1,
                "target": 0,
            },
            {
                "source": 2,
                "target": 0,
            },
            {
                "source": 3,
                "target": 0,
            },
            {
                "source": 4,
                "target": 0,
            },
            ]
        }

        // declare initial variables
        var svg = d3.select("svg")
        width = window.innerWidth
        height = window.innerHeight
        thisNode = null;

        // define cavnas area to draw everything
        svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("class", "canvas")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
                svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        // iniital force simulation
        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
                return d.id;
            }).distance(100))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-80))
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("attraceForce", d3.forceManyBody().strength(70));

        var node_group = null
        var link_group = null

        update()

        /*
        console.log("Initial Nodes")
        console.log(graph.nodes)
        console.log("------------------")
        */

        function update() {
            //define group and join - nodes
            node_group = svg.selectAll(".node_group")
                .data(graph.nodes, d => d.id)

            //exit, remove
            node_group.exit().remove();

            //enter
            var enterN = node_group.enter()
                .append("g").attr("class", "node_group");

            //append
            enterN.append("circle")
                .attr("class", "node_circle")
                .attr("r", 20)
                .on("contextmenu", contextMenu)
               

            enterN.append("text")
                .attr("class", "node_label")
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.name
                })

            //merge
            node_group = node_group.merge(enterN);

            node_group.call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragStarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragEnded)
                )

            //###LINKS

            //define group and join -links
            link_group = svg.selectAll(".link_group")
                .data(graph.links)

            //exit, remove
            link_group.exit().remove();

            //enter
            var enterL = link_group.enter()
                .append("g").attr("class", "link_group")

            //append
            enterL.append("line")
                .attr("class", "link_stroke")
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("sroke-width", 2)

            //merge
            link_group = link_group.merge(enterL);


            simulation
                .nodes(graph.nodes)
                .on("tick", ticked);

            simulation
                .force("link")
                .links(graph.links)

            simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
        }

        function contextMenu(d) {
            thisNode = d

            event.preventDefault()

            var contextMenu = document.getElementById("context-menu")
            contextMenu.style.top = event.clientY + "px"
            contextMenu.style.left = event.clientX + "px"
            contextMenu.classList.add("active")

            window.addEventListener("click", function () {
                contextMenu.classList.remove("active")
            })

            document.getElementById("addObject").addEventListener("click", addNode)
            document.getElementById("removeObject").addEventListener("click", removeNodeClicked)

        }

        function removeNodeClicked() {
            removeNode(thisNode)
        }

        function addNode() {
            var newID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)

            /*
            console.log("Before adding Node")
            console.log(graph.nodes)
            console.log("------------------")
            */

            graph.links.push({source: newID, target: thisNode.id})

            graph.nodes.push({ id: newID, name: newID })

            /*
            console.log("After adding Node")
            console.log(graph.nodes)
            console.log("------------------")
            */

            update()
        }

        function removeNode(thisNode) {
            var indexOfNode = graph.nodes.indexOf(thisNode)

            var indexOfLink = graph.links.findIndex(element => element.source.id === thisNode.id)

            /*
            console.log("Before removing Node")
            console.log(graph.nodes)
            console.log("------------------")
            */

            graph.links.splice(indexOfLink,1)

            graph.nodes.splice(indexOfNode, 1)

            /*
            console.log("After removing Node")
            console.log(graph.nodes)
            console.log("------------------")
            */

            update()
        }

        function ticked() {
            // update link positions
            link_group
                .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

            // update node positions
            node_group
                .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")"; });
        }

        function dragStarted(d) {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }

        function dragged(d) {
            d.fx = d3.event.x;
            d.fy = d3.event.y;
        }

        function dragEnded(d) {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = undefined;
            d.fy = undefined;
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason you're appending the `<line>` inside `<g>` elements, and then in the `ticked` function you're setting the `x1`, `y1`, `x2` and `y2` properties to those groups, not to the lines.

That said, the minimal change for that code to work is, in the `ticked` function:

```
link_group.select("line")
    .attr("x1", etc...
```

However, I'd ditch the groups altogether and append just the lines.

Here is your code with that change only:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>D3v4 enter().exit().remove()</title>
    <!-- favcon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="https://networkrepository.com/favicon.png">
    <!-- call external d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <!-- import multiselection framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.js"></script>
    <!-- import "font awesome" stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .canvas {
        background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
    }

    .node_group {
        fill: whitesmoke;
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 2px
    }

    .node_label {
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 0px;
        fill: black
    }

    .tooltip {
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: left;
        background: rgb(245, 245, 245);
        border: 2px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border-style: solid;
        pointer-events: none;
        line-height: 150%;
        padding: 8px 10px;
    }

    #context-menu {
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 10000;
        width: 190px;
        background: whitesmoke;
        border: 2px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border-color: white;
        border-style: solid;
        transform: scale(0);
        transform-origin: top left;
    }

    #context-menu.active {
        transform: scale(1);
        transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out;
    }

    #context-menu .item {
        padding: 8px 10px;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: black;
    }

    #context-menu .item i {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    #context-menu hr {
        margin: 5px 0px;
        border-color: whitesmoke;
    }

    #context-menu .item:hover {
        background: lightblue;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <!-- right click context menu -->
    <div id="context-menu">
        <div id="addObject" class="item">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Node
        </div>
        <div id="removeObject" class="item">
            <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> Remove Node
        </div>
    </div>

    <svg id="svg"> </svg>


    <!-- call script where the main application is written -->
    <script>
        var graph = {
            "nodes": [{
                "id": 0,
                "name": "Company",
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "1",
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "2",
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "3",
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "4",
            }
            ],
            "links": [{
                "source": 1,
                "target": 0,
            },
            {
                "source": 2,
                "target": 0,
            },
            {
                "source": 3,
                "target": 0,
            },
            {
                "source": 4,
                "target": 0,
            },
            ]
        }

        // declare initial variables
        var svg = d3.select("svg")
        width = window.innerWidth
        height = window.innerHeight
        thisNode = null;

        // define cavnas area to draw everything
        svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("class", "canvas")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
                svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        // iniital force simulation
        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
                return d.id;
            }).distance(100))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-80))
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("attraceForce", d3.forceManyBody().strength(70));

        var node_group = null
        var link_group = null

        update()

        /*
        console.log("Initial Nodes")
        console.log(graph.nodes)
        console.log("------------------")
        */

        function update() {
            //define group and join - nodes
            node_group = svg.selectAll(".node_group")
                .data(graph.nodes, d => d.id)

            //exit, remove
            node_group.exit().remove();

            //enter
            var enterN = node_group.enter()
                .append("g").attr("class", "node_group");

            //append
            enterN.append("circle")
                .attr("class", "node_circle")
                .attr("r", 20)
                .on("contextmenu", contextMenu)
               

            enterN.append("text")
                .attr("class", "node_label")
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.name
                })

            //merge
            node_group = node_group.merge(enterN);

            node_group.call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragStarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragEnded)
                )

            //###LINKS

            //define group and join -links
            link_group = svg.selectAll(".link_group")
                .data(graph.links)

            //exit, remove
            link_group.exit().remove();

            //enter
            var enterL = link_group.enter()
                .append("g").attr("class", "link_group")

            //append
            enterL.append("line")
                .attr("class", "link_stroke")
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("sroke-width", 2)

            //merge
            link_group = link_group.merge(enterL);


            simulation
                .nodes(graph.nodes)
                .on("tick", ticked);

            simulation
                .force("link")
                .links(graph.links)

            simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
        }

        function contextMenu(d) {
            thisNode = d

            event.preventDefault()

            var contextMenu = document.getElementById("context-menu")
            contextMenu.style.top = event.clientY + "px"
            contextMenu.style.left = event.clientX + "px"
            contextMenu.classList.add("active")

            window.addEventListener("click", function () {
                contextMenu.classList.remove("active")
            })

            document.getElementById("addObject").addEventListener("click", addNode)
            document.getElementById("removeObject").addEventListener("click", removeNodeClicked)

        }

        function removeNodeClicked() {
            removeNode(thisNode)
        }

        function addNode() {
            var newID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)

            /*
            console.log("Before adding Node")
            console.log(graph.nodes)
            console.log("------------------")
            */

            graph.links.push({source: newID, target: thisNode.id})

            graph.nodes.push({ id: newID, name: newID })

            /*
            console.log("After adding Node")
            console.log(graph.nodes)
            console.log("------------------")
            */

            update()
        }

        function removeNode(thisNode) {
            var indexOfNode = graph.nodes.indexOf(thisNode)

            var indexOfLink = graph.links.findIndex(element => element.source.id === thisNode.id)

            /*
            console.log("Before removing Node")
            console.log(graph.nodes)
            console.log("------------------")
            */

            graph.links.splice(indexOfLink,1)

            graph.nodes.splice(indexOfNode, 1)

            /*
            console.log("After removing Node")
            console.log(graph.nodes)
            console.log("------------------")
            */

            update()
        }

        function ticked() {
            // update link positions
            link_group.select("line")
                .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

            // update node positions
            node_group
                .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")"; });
        }

        function dragStarted(d) {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }

        function dragged(d) {
            d.fx = d3.event.x;
            d.fy = d3.event.y;
        }

        function dragEnded(d) {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = undefined;
            d.fy = undefined;
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I got you but I do not understand why it would not work with the group. My main code contains for each link, text path´s and label´s. I thought to put everything in one huge backpack and reallocate this backpack, with ticked(). It is working for the nodes too, as I got the node group itself and the appended circles and text. Still confusing for me.

Comment: It is working for the nodes because groups have `transform` as a presentation attribute. As I said, you don't need the groups for the links, so just create the enter-exit-update selection for the lines and change their positions in the `ticked` function.